# windowSoftInputMode Not Working on Webview Element

Tags: android, android-layout, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

I tried to set `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize` in manifest file so that when I click on an input inside a `webview`, the keyboard does not cover the input field.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Seems like it is not working on webview elements.
I tried to set it within `AndroidManifest.xml` and also on the `WebView` element itself inside activity_main.xml.

There is simply no way I can make the **webview element** move up, once the keyboard is displayed.

Any idea on how to solve that issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add below code inside `onCreate()` of your `Activity`. This should help in preventing keyboard from hiding **input field**

```
YourActivity.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: It says "cannot resolve methode 'getActivity()'" - what am I missing? Sorry - brand new to Java. Thanks :)

Comment: I've modified my answer. please check again

Comment: Thanks - that's what I tried myself beforehand. No success. I click on an input inside the webview element but the webview element does not change in height nor moves upwards. Did you try it?

Comment: any chance you could share a demo project somehow? I guess I have some small mistake elsewhere then.

Answer (score 0):

Try making below changes in the class where `webView` is accessible. This shall help.

```
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way as native.

[KeyboardEventListener from Ian Alexander.](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-detect-if-the-android-keyboard-is-open-269b255a90f5)

Warning:

> Unfortunately, if you use android:windowSoftInputMode=”adjustResize" these methods will be no use for you. This method relies on the underlying view staying the same height when the keyboard is drawn — adjustResize causes the underlying view to change size.

You need to create a helper class for keyboard events:

```
class KeyboardEventListener(private val activity: AppCompatActivity, fragment: Fragment? = null, private val callback: (isOpen: Boolean) -> Unit): LifecycleObserver {
private val listener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private var lastState: Boolean = activity.isKeyboardOpen()

    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        val isOpen = activity.isKeyboardOpen()
        if (isOpen == lastState) {
            return
        } else {
            dispatchKeyboardEvent(isOpen)
            lastState = isOpen
        }
    }
}

init {
    // Dispatch the current state of the keyboard
    dispatchKeyboardEvent(activity.isKeyboardOpen())
    // Make the component lifecycle aware
    fragment?.lifecycle?.addObserver(this) ?: activity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    registerKeyboardListener()
}

private fun registerKeyboardListener() {
    activity.getRootView().viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
}

private fun dispatchKeyboardEvent(isOpen: Boolean) {
    when {
        isOpen  -> callback(true)
        !isOpen -> callback(false)
    }
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(value = Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
@CallSuper
fun onLifecyclePause() {
    unregisterKeyboardListener()
}

private fun unregisterKeyboardListener() {
    activity.getRootView().viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
}
```

Extensions which you need:

```
class ExtensionMethods() {
fun Activity.isKeyboardOpen(): Boolean {
    val visibleBounds = Rect()
    this.getRootView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(visibleBounds)
    val heightDiff = getRootView().height - visibleBounds.height()
    val marginOfError = this.convertDpToPx(50F).roundToInt()
    return heightDiff > marginOfError }

fun Context.convertDpToPx(dp: Float): Float {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        dp,
        this.resources.displayMetrics
    ) }

fun Activity.getRootView(): View { return findViewById(android.R.id.content) }

fun View.adjustResize(activity: Activity, isOpen: Boolean) {
    val paddingBottom = if (isOpen) activity.getKeyboardHeight() else 0
    this.setPadding(0, 0, 0, paddingBottom)
}
fun Activity.getKeyboardHeight(): Int {
    val visibleBounds = Rect()
    this.getRootView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(visibleBounds)
    return getRootView().height - visibleBounds.height()}}
```

Usage:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    KeyboardEventListener(currentActivity, currentFragment) { isOpen ->
        binding.container.adjustResize(getMainActivity(), isOpen)
    }
}
```